# How to unite the region of ParametricPlot and set up the mesh for FEM?

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I have used the `ParametricPlot` to plot the sector of the disk and use `Show` to combine them in one picture, however it cannot be converted to the region and cannot use the `RegionUnite`, and cannot be meshed by `ToElementMesh`, **so how to convert the plot to region and get the mesh later for FEM and boundary conditions indication?

The code and its results are as follows:

```
R1 = 4/100;
R2 = 7/100;
R3 = 8/100;


ToothNumber = 8;
SlotNumber = ToothNumber;
RectangleNumber = ToothNumber + SlotNumber;

betaSlot = Pi/8;
betaPole = 2*Pi/(ToothNumber) - betaSlot;

thetaInitial = Pi/12;

regionR2R3 = 
  ParametricPlot[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 
    R2, R3}];
region[n_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta]}, {theta, 
    thetaInitial + betaPole + (n - 1)*(betaPole + betaSlot), 
    thetaInitial + betaPole + 
     betaSlot + (n - 1)*(betaPole + betaSlot)}, {r, R1, R2}];
regionR1R2 = 
  Show[Table[region[n], {n, 1, ToothNumber}], PlotRange -> All];
regionAll = Show[{regionR1R2, regionR2R3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The above code can plot the right region (But it is not in region format) and the output figure is as this:

[image]

The following code doesn't work:

```
RegionUnion[regionR1R2, regionR2R3]
\[CapitalOmega] = regionAll;
bounds = {{-R3, R3}, {-R3, R3}};
meshAll = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], bounds]
```

Comment: `mesh = ToElementMesh[regionAll // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics];
mesh["Wireframe"]`

Comment: @cvgmt, excellent and thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way maybe replace all the `ParametricPlot` to `ParametricRegion` and use `RegionUnion`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
R1 = 4/100;
R2 = 7/100;
R3 = 8/100;


ToothNumber = 8;
SlotNumber = ToothNumber;
RectangleNumber = ToothNumber + SlotNumber;

betaSlot = Pi/8;
betaPole = 2*Pi/(ToothNumber) - betaSlot;

thetaInitial = Pi/12;

regionR2R3 = 
  ParametricRegion[{r Cos[theta], 
    r Sin[theta]}, {{theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, R2, R3}}];
region[n_] := 
  ParametricRegion[{r Cos[theta], 
    r Sin[theta]}, {{theta, 
     thetaInitial + betaPole + (n - 1)*(betaPole + betaSlot), 
     thetaInitial + betaPole + 
      betaSlot + (n - 1)*(betaPole + betaSlot)}, {r, R1, R2}}];

regionR1R2 = RegionUnion[Table[region[n], {n, 1, ToothNumber}]];
regionAll = RegionUnion[regionR1R2, regionR2R3];
mesh = RegionPlot[regionAll] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics // 
  ToBoundaryMesh
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer and thank you very much! However what is the difference of `Region` and `RegionPlot`,as I cannot get the mesh for your code.

Comment: @fhrl  Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; I am using version 13.2.1 ,the code work for me.  If we  want to use `Region`, we can using  `mesh = Region[regionAll] // Show // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics // 
  ToBoundaryMesh`

Comment: Well received and thank you!